ValueError: The number of qubits of the circuit (127) does not match the number of qubits of the ()-th observable (4)
I am quite new to qiskit and i am trying to build a qaoa for portfolio optimization, but i get this error and i am not able to resolve this issue: ValueError: The number of qubits of the circuit (127) does not match the number of qubits of the ()-th observable (4).
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, Session
from qiskit.primitives import BackendEstimatorV2
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
import numpy as np

# Load your IBM Quantum account
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum")

# Select the least busy backend
backend = service.least_busy(operational=True, simulator=False)
print(f"Selected backend: {backend.name}")

num_assets = 4  # Number of assets (qubits)
q2 = 0.5  # Risk factor

# Create a quantum circuit for QAOA with num_assets qubits
qc = QuantumCircuit(num_assets, num_assets)

# Apply Hadamard gates to all qubits
qc.h(range(num_assets))

# Define QAOA parameters for multiple layers (reps)
gamma = [Parameter(f'γ{i}') for i in range(3)]
beta = [Parameter(f'β{i}') for i in range(3)]

# Apply parameterized gates with entangling gates (beta and gamma angles)
for i in range(3):  # Number of repetitions (layers)
    for qubit in range(num_assets):
        qc.rz(gamma[i], qubit)
    for qubit in range(num_assets):
        qc.rx(beta[i], qubit)
    for qubit in range(num_assets - 1):
        qc.cz(qubit, qubit + 1)

# Bind parameters with specific values
param_values = {gamma[i]: 2 * q2 for i in range(3)}
param_values.update({beta[i]: np.pi / 2 for i in range(3)})

# Assign the parameters to the circuit
qc = qc.assign_parameters(param_values)

# Add measurements at the end for each qubit
qc.measure(range(num_assets), range(num_assets))

# Transpile the circuit for the selected backend with an initial layout that matches num_assets
initial_layout = list(range(num_assets))
qc_transpiled = transpile(qc, backend=backend, initial_layout=initial_layout, optimization_level=1)

# Define the observable correctly matching the number of qubits in the circuit
observable = SparsePauliOp.from_list([("Z" * num_assets, 1.0)])  # Ensure this matches num_assets

# Create a session for the Estimator and run it
with Session(service=service, backend=backend) as session:
    estimator = BackendEstimatorV2(backend=backend)
    job = estimator.run([(qc_transpiled, observable)])
    result = job.result()

# Print the result
print(result)

ValueError: The number of qubits of the circuit (127) does not match the number of qubits of the ()-th observable (4).

According to the documentation

To ensure faster and more efficient results, as of 1 March 2024, circuits and observables need to be transformed to only use instructions supported by the system (referred to as instruction set architecture (ISA) circuits and observables) before being submitted to the Qiskit Runtime primitives. See the transpilation documentation for instructions to transform circuits. Due to this change, the primitives will no longer perform layout or routing operations.

So, you need to apply the transpiled circuit layout to the observable before passing it to the estimator
observable_isa = observable.apply_layout(layout=qc_transpiled.layout)
job = estimator.run([(qc_transpiled, observable_isa)])

